# How to delete ALL Azure resources with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to empty my Azure account from all resources and there's too much to remove individually in the portal. Looking for a powershell script to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? can you show some code? any errors etc?

Comment: I'm a complete PS beginner, don't know where to start. Doesn't have to be PS, just want everything gone...

Comment: Does it have to be PowerShell? can you not delete subscription through portal? Deleting a subscription will kill all resources inside of the subscription.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As resources in Azure are grouped into resource groups(RG), that would probably be the easiest way to go about this. Use these cmdlets to do this.

- [Get-AzureRmResourceGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603831.aspx)
- [Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603755.aspx)

Once you have retrieved all the RGs, you can pipe the results with the | character to the Remove cmdlet and iterate through them with a ForEach loop. Give it a go, it is the best way to learn, as opposed to simply asking for the solution on here.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use powershell, just delete your RGs from the portal. I assume you think it would take too long because you are looking at the individual resources and not their RGs, but if you really do have that many RGs, then scripting is best.

Comment: Is there a way to delete selected Resource Groups like; get an array of RG names and delete once. I don't want to delete all the RGs. Please if there is a way to do this, I'll appreciate if you can show it here

Comment: I guess you want something like: $rgNames = "name1","name2"
foreach($name in $rgNames){
    Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where ResourceGroupName -like $name
}. This gets all RGs that have names that start with that variable value. Then you can do the same as the answer, pass the result to the remove cmdlet to delete it.

Answer (score 8):

```
#It will delete all resources without asking any confirmation
Login-AzureRmAccount

$rgName = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup 

Foreach($name in $rgName)
{
Write-Host $name.ResourceGroupName
Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $name.ResourceGroupName -Verbose -Force
}
```

Comment: Hey! I was using your script, thanks for that! Untill it stopped working with the following error:
```Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.```
Any idea why would it stop working?

Comment: May be your azure resource group is null

Answer (score 5):

A script like that could be really harmful... but also very useful.

I've created a little script and add little security on it to avoid nuking the wrong subscription.

The script asks you to login-in then list all the subscriptions that this account has access. Once you specify which one, it will list all the resource grouped by resource group. Then as a final warning, it will require one last validation before nuking everything.

```
# Login
Login-AzureRmAccount 

# Get a list of all Azure subscript that the user can access
$allSubs = Get-AzureRmSubscription 

$allSubs | Sort-Object SubscriptionName | Format-Table -Property SubscriptionName, SubscriptionId, State


$theSub = Read-Host "Enter the subscriptionId you want to clean"

Write-Host "You select the following subscription. (it will be display 15 sec.)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $theSub | Select-AzureRmSubscription 

#Get all the resources groups

$allRG = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup


foreach ( $g in $allRG){

    Write-Host $g.ResourceGroupName -ForegroundColor Yellow 
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
    $allResources = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains $g.ResourceGroupName

    if($allResources){
        $allResources | Format-Table -Property Name, ResourceName
    }
    else{
         Write-Host "-- empty--`n"
    } 
    Write-Host "`n`n------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
}


$lastValidation = Read-Host "Do you wich to delete ALL the resouces previously listed? (YES/ NO)"

if($lastValidation.ToLower().Equals("yes")){

    foreach ( $g in $allRG){

        Write-Host "Deleting " $g.ResourceGroupName 
        Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $g.ResourceGroupName -Force -WhatIf

    }
}
else{
     Write-Host "Aborded. Nothing was deleted." -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

The code is available on [GitHub: AzurePowerTools](https://github.com/FBoucher/AzurePowerTools)

Answer (score 3):

switch to the poweshell shell in Azure and run this command to wipe everything..

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -verbose -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the ask was for Powershell, but if anyone is interested here is for Azure CLI

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: Be careful as this code in intended to delete ALL Resources in a subscription. Use at your own risk.

# Set The correct Subscription
az account set -s "<Subscription_name / Id>"

# Get All resource groups and loop to delete them
for rg_name in `az group list -o tsv --query [*].name`; do
        echo Deleting ${rg_name}
        az group delete -n ${rg_name} --yes --no-wait
done
```

Answer (score 1):

## Updated for new Azure PowerShell module Az

```
# Login
Connect-AzAccount 

# Get a list of all Azure subscript that the user can access
$allSubs = Get-azSubscription 

$allSubs | Sort-Object SubscriptionName | Format-Table -Property SubscriptionName, SubscriptionId, State


$theSub = Read-Host "Enter the subscriptionId you want to clean"

Write-Host "You select the following subscription. (it will be display 15 sec.)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-azSubscription -SubscriptionId $theSub | Select-azSubscription 

#Get all the resources groups

$allRG = Get-azResourceGroup


foreach ( $g in $allRG){

    Write-Host $g.ResourceGroupName -ForegroundColor Yellow 
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
    $allResources = Get-azResource -ResourceGroupName $g.ResourceGroupName | FT

    if($allResources){
        $allResources | Format-Table -Property Name, ResourceName
    }
    else{
         Write-Host "-- empty--`n"
    } 
    Write-Host "`n`n------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
}


$lastValidation = Read-Host "Do you wich to delete ALL the resouces previously listed? (YES/ NO)"

if($lastValidation.ToLower().Equals("yes")){

    foreach ( $g in $allRG){

        Write-Host "Deleting " $g.ResourceGroupName 
        Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $g.ResourceGroupName | Remove-AzResourceGroup -Verbose -Force

    }
}
else{
     Write-Host "Aborded. Nothing was deleted." -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all resources from Azure Resource Group but to keep the group with its settings:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName | Remove-AzResource -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command can be used to delete all resources

```
Get-AzResource | Remove-AzResource -force
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a one-line (please log in using az login)

```
az group list | ConvertFrom-Json | % {az group delete --name $_.name -y}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Azure PowerShell command to delete all resource.

```
Get-AzResource | ForEach { Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $_.ResourceId -Force -Confirm:$False }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple pipeline with Az module.

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Remove-AzResourceGroup -Force
```

Comment: Please, describe how this answer differs from the accepted one. Now it is unclear, it contains exactly the same.

Comment: Help me please, where is the same answer? I wrote a pipeline with Az module.

Comment: @astentx I would be very grateful if you will show me "exactly the same" answer. Thanks!

Comment: The [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36405843/2778710): "Once you have retrieved all the RGs, *you can pipe the results with the | character* to the Remove cmdlet and iterate through them with a ForEach loop." I hope someone who uses PS (or any other shell) knows about pipe

Comment: Sorry, still don't get where did you saw the "exactly the same" answer. 
1.) Difference between PS modules;
2.) No ForEach loop in my case;
3). There is no ready code, only links to cmdlets.