# Remove all resources from an Azure account

Tags: azure, cloud, resource-cleanup

There are a couple of AWS Nuke-like projects for AWS meant for removing all allocated resources. Is there such a tool for Azure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete ALL Azure resources with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403597/how-to-delete-all-azure-resources-with-powershell)

Comment: It's close. I'd use it if there is nothing else. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: [Remove-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azresourcegroup?view=azps-4.7.0) is used for the new version. Azure PowerShell has migrated from `AzureRM` to `Az`.

Comment: Here is a cleanup script that nukes all resources in a given subscription: [Nuke an Azure Subscription](http://www.frankysnotes.com/2016/12/need-to-nuke-azure-subscription.html)